# special characters/chinese language text not rendering properly in csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, character-encoding, fastercsv

I am using charset=utf-8; in the csv options. The chinese characters and some special characters ( for eg :- '»',  ) are still not rendered correctly in the csv, though the same text looks fine in the browser.

Comment: What method are you using to save this csv file?

Comment: a) How are you determining that the file is not displayed correctly (i.e. what are you using to look at it)? b) How are you creating the csv?

Comment: What method are you using to create your CSV file? If you paste chinese characthers into NotePad and save as UTF-8 it works fine.

Comment: i am using openoffice 3.2 to view the csv. I am using send_data to save the csv file, and to_csv method available in fastercsv-1.5.3 to convert to csv.

Comment: What's it look like in a normal UTF-8 capable text editor?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu-10.04. Is gedit UTF-8 enabled? Openoffice is. It shows the unicode for those characters in both of them.

Comment: &#28195; &#25171; &#38134; A sample of what i get in the csv.I assume these are unicode for chinese characters. A google search on any one of them individually shows the corresponding chinese character.

Comment: No, `&#28195;` is the [HTML escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) for the Unicode codepoint 28195. I.e., the output is geared towards display in an HTML context (browser). Non-browser apps probably won't know what to do with this data. You're not saving your data as UTF-8, you're saving it as HTML escaped ASCII.

Comment: here's a sample from my database.yml:                               development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode                                                    shouldn't it enough to ensure that the data is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: For the sake of getting some coherent facts: Please update your question and include: 1) The exact code you're using to generate the file. 2) Sample raw input. 3) Sample raw output. (*Raw* meaning "the direct output of your code as looked at in a text editor or on the command line, not in a browser or OOo.")

Comment: Thanx deceze, for pointing me in the right direction. Actually, We are scraping data using scrAPI, and that's where the problem lies. Trying to include the utf-8 option while scraping.

Answer (score -1):

I am using r:ISO-8859-1 for asia specific region